# Xcode build failing: PCH files found, but invalid

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4

I ran my iPhone app (not for the first time) and after checking every things function and being quite satisfied I quit the simulator. Than I added a period in my code, saved it, and ran it. The code didn't compile so i took the period out and once again saved it and ran it. However it now gives me these 3 errors [image: errors]. I understand basically what it is saying however i do not know how to fix it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Not sure how you got there, but your Precompiled Headers are invalid. Just force Xcode to recreate them.

Hold down the **option** key and select **Clean Build Folder...** from the **Product** menu.

Then try to build again.

Comment: Sounds like a clean is required to me too.

Comment: Works for building inside Xcode, but for cmd line xcodebuild, the error still persists :(

Comment: EDIT: "touch" you PCH file first and retry  https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4935870

Answer (score 1):

A simple clean also worked for me (did not need to clean the entire build folder).

Comment: Same here, a simple clean was enough. In my case, the error appeared just after updating xCode.